# Is provisioning file required to build iOS project for relase?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm trying to build an iOS project and distribute through OTA (Over The Air). And it looks like I need a provisioning file to in the process, but I don't have any iOS devices (therefore the UDID) required for generating the provisioning file. Does this mean, we have to buy iOS device for releasing an app?

(I can't proceed in the distribution provisioning file generation process without Device)

[image: cant proceed]

Comment: you do need a provisioning profile, but you dont need a device (although you really should have if you want to test properly). but you will need an apple dev licence to get a provisioning profile

Comment: but when i try to generate provisioning file, they tell me to create the device, and i can't proceed. (and I do have an apple dev license)

Comment: if its a development provisioning profile yes, you probably want an ad hoc one for distributing to other devices, but you will need their udid's. otherwise no need for provisioning profile if there are no devices involved... or am i misunderstanding something

Comment: I chose distribution provisioning file, but they still tell me to choose a device (see updated answer please)

Comment: and by other devices, i mean your clients or devices not in your possession

Comment: ye the provisioning profile needs to contain some devices, otherwise the profile is useless, it doesnt have to be your own device, but the devices you add are the ones that will be able to run the app

Comment: Okay, that means Apple doesn't allow those who don't have any iOS device to release an app? (well, as you said we should test on actual device, so that sounds legit tho..)

Comment: @Ryo - with out testing your app in device how would u know it works in perfectly in all devices , thats the reason initially we created the provisonal profile and p12 using developement mode and we deug it , if every thing is fine we upload our app to live

Comment: If you're building an App in Release for a Client, yes, you will need a Device. This will be consider like an Ad Hoc Distribution - Provisioning Profile. And you need the Device ID of your Client, so he can install your app in his device.

Comment: Anbu.Karthik, bluezald:
 Thank you for the comments. In my case, I was gong to test app using client's multiple devices whose UDIDs I can't know yet, and wanted to use OTA for app download. And wanted to finish the setup beforehands. I'll make this question solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to build and release the app without provisioning file. And we need at least 1 UDID for that. So it's impossible to publish the app without UDID.

Thanks guys.